# Refresh component after router.navigateByUrl to the same URL with different parameters

Tags: angular, url, router, reload

I have a Router `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` that includes the following route:

> { path: 'employee/:id', component: EmployeeComponent }

With an EmployeeComponent component already inside the router-outlet with a specific employee, I do the following in my code: `this.router.navigateByUrl('/employee/'+this.employee2);`

The url changes but the component does not execute the ngOnInit() method with the new Employee, and the content is not refreshed. I need to instantiate a new EmployeeComponent with an EmployeeComponent already on my router, or refresh the existing one. How can fix that?

Comment: IMO you should make use of `ActivatedRoute`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to inject "ActivatedRoute" and subscribe the params

```
constructor(route:ActivatedRoute){
      route.params.subscribe(val=>{ 
       //    add to do function()
      })
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `AcitvatedRoute`.

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
```

Using **Params**

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.route.params.subscribe(param=>{
    console.log(+params['id'])
  })
}
```